# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'key_schema' referenced before assignment

Tags: amazon-dynamodb-dax

Im trying to integrate DAX with Pynamodb(working on an existing pull request). While testing the batch write method from aws DAX sdk I'm facing the below issue. Any help is appreciated.

```
/.virtualenvs/PynamoDB/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amazondax/DaxClient.pyc in batch_write_item(self, **kwargs)
     98             Stubs.write_batchWriteItem_116217951_1(request, tube)
     99 
--> 100             result = self._decode_result('BatchWriteItem', request, Assemblers.batchWriteItem_116217951_1, tube)
    101             result = self._resolve_attribute_values(result, tube)
    102             return result

/.virtualenvs/PynamoDB/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amazondax/DaxClient.pyc in _decode_result(self, operation_name, request, assembler, tube)
    223         if status == DaxClient.SUCCESS:
    224             tube.skip() #  Throw away the empty error header
--> 225             return assembler(request, tube)
    226         else:
    227             return self._handle_error(operation_name, tube)

/.virtualenvs/PynamoDB/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amazondax/Assemblers.pyc in batchWriteItem_116217951_1(request, tube)
    115 
    116         for _ in range(num_items, 0, -2):
--> 117             key = AttributeValueDecoder._decode_key_bytes(_dec, key_schema)
    118             if _dec.try_decode_null():
    119                 # DeleteRequest

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'key_schema' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 1):

<del>This is a known issue that I hope to have a fix out for shortly.</del>

This is fixed in version 1.0.4 of the DAX Python client.

Comment: @eldos: The latest version has a fix; I updated the answer.